# Magento - get order id from increment id

Tags: magento

How do you get the **Order Id** from magento **Order Increment Id**?

I can use the following get the product id from SKU:

```
$product_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku('ABCD1234');
```

The above example lets me get just the database entity_id of a product without loading everything. I want to achieve the same for order.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want to fetch only order_id then simply use mysql query, if you want order_id in for loop, it is not load entire order object and it is very quick and fast, you don't need to load order object model.

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$result=$write->query("SELECT entity_id FROM `sales_flat_order` WHERE `increment_id` = 'your increment id' ");
$row = $result->fetch();
echo $row['entity_id'];
```

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was after. Btw, why "core_write", isn't core_read enough as we are doing select only?

Comment: I did a slightly optimised version of the above sample code (confirmed working) : http://pastebin.com/gtpDbsbR. Thanks again.

Comment: @StefanBrendle - try my example http://pastebin.com/gtpDbsbR - this works with table prefixes automatically.

Comment: Never run queries directly in the database, bad example

Comment: This really should not be the accepted answer. Yes it works. No it's not even remotely close to the way anything should be done in Magento. Use @Laizer's answer below instead.

Comment: @Brian If you only want Id from order then there is no need to load entire Order object,OP need this in For loop, It will result in some performance degradation due to heavy db load.

Comment: @Mufaddal I don't disagree with that portion of your answer. It's definitely more "lightweight" than loading the entire object, but you're setting the DB table name as a literal string instead of using something like `Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order_grid')` so that your script is aware of DB table prefixes and works on all Magento installs regardless of prefix. Just because you only needed to provide a solution for a single use case, doesn't mean that solution shouldn't be built in the most versatile and future-proof way. Hence comments like Stefan's above.

Comment: Hello SQL Injection. (-1 by the way)

Answer (score 34):

In a Magento model, the load method can take an optional second argument of what attribute to load by. 
So, in your case, the following should work:

```
   $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($incrementId, 'increment_id');
   $id = $order->getId();
```

In more complex cases, e.g. where you want to load by a combination of fields, you can load a collection, and get the first element of the collection.  In your case, you'd do it like this:

```
   $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
      ->addFieldToFilter('increment_id', $increment_id)
      ->getFirstItem();
```

Comment: Will this not load the entire order? I need to do this in a for loop for several orders, and I fear this might result in some performance degradation due to heavy db load. is there a lightweight way of loading the order id?

Comment: If all you need is the id, then @Mufaddal's approach will be lighter weight.

Answer (score 20):

You can load an order from the IncrementId.

```
$orderIncrementId = "1000001";
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
echo $order->getId();
```